# Expanded widget not working with Inkwell when used inside a Row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have the following code snippet

```
child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: widget.items
            .map((item) => InkWell(
                  child: Expanded(child: buildIconItem(item)),
                  onTap: ()=>(),
                ))
            .toList(),
      );


This is my IconItem
Widget buildIconItem(IconButtonItem item) {
    Color color = item.disabled
        ? Colors.grey.shade400
        : item.selected
            ? Theme.of(context).accentColor
            : Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.color;
    TextStyle textStyle = TextStyle(color: color);
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        ImageIcon(item.iconImage.image, size: 35, color: color),
        SizedBox(
          height: 6,
        ),
        Text(item.imageTitle, style: textStyle),
        SizedBox(
          height: 6,
        ),
        Visibility(child: Text(item.subTitle, style: textStyle),
          visible: item.subTitle != null,),
      ],
    );
  }
```

I expect each item to be expanded and between the ripple effect of one item to another item , there should not be any space left that doesn't show the ripple effect.

Right now , the ui looks like between each item there's a gap because of `spaceEvenly` flag and this gap doesn't get the ripple effect from inkwell. So i want to expand each item.

Comment: removing 'mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly' might work, since you are making it expanded.

Comment: nope , it puts everything at the start leaving empty space after the items

Comment: The expanded is inside the InkWell have you tried to put the expanded as the parent of InkWell?

Comment: yes it worked . Thanks @Henok

Comment: you are very welcome I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expanded is inside the InkWell swapping the expanded as the parent of InkWell might fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**If your issue is not solved by rapping it with Expanded.**

Consider rapping Ink with Material Widget and then rapping Material with Expanded.
Expanded->  Material -> Ink

[image]